# How to check which ciphers are included in "HIGH" ciphers constant

Tags: ssl, openssl, cipher

From the documentation I found

> HIGH
> "High" encryption cipher suites. This currently means those with key lengths larger than 128 bits, and some cipher suites with 128-bit keys.

The sentence "and some cipher suites with 128-bit keys" is a bit vague here.
How can I obtain an exact list of all ciphers coverd by "HIGH"

Comment: the basic requirement is that the key length is *more* than 128, but for some specific cipher suites, 128bit is acceptable. a cipher suite is made of a protocol, a key derivation algorithm, a key exchange algorithm, a hashing algorithm, an encryption algorithm, and a mode. with some combinations AES128 is acceptable, and with others, it is not. expect the list to change over time.

Answer (score 0):

I think we can use openssls

```
openssl ciphers HIGH
```

Which will print the list